# jquery ajax, how to call onload event in handle page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I have try to post value from page a to page b via jquery ajax.
But when I need a onload event in the handle page.  I tried 2 ways, but all failed. How to call correctly or it is a bug?

a.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: "b.php", 
         dataType: "html",
         type: 'POST', 
         data: "word="+"hello", 
         success: function(data){ 
            $("#show").html(data);
         }
      });
    });
});
</script>
<a href="#">click</a>
<div id="show"></div>
```

b.php

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   function callhello() {
       alert('<?php echo $_POST['word']; ?>');
       //many other code, for a test, I moved them. and replace a alert call.
   }
</script>
<body onload="JavaScript:callhello()"><!-- way 1, put onload here, not run -->
    Blah~~ Blah~~ Blah~~
<script language="JavaScript">// change to text/javascript or even remove, no effect
window.onload = function() {
  callhello();
};
</script><!-- way 2, put onload here, still not run. -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you insert HTML into your document, any scripts are executed with the document's context.  That means that `window.onload` refers to the `load` event of the current `window`.  Given that the insertion is delayed (by waiting for the `click` event), the `window.onload` event has already been triggered.  You can attach a function to the `load` event, but it will never be triggered.

It's probably best to put the function call straight into your `script` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // the language attribute is deprecated
  callhello();
</script>
```

This means that jQuery will execute the script as it's added to the  document.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

---

You need to change:

```
function callhello() {
    alert('<?php echo $_POST['word']; ?>');
    //many other code, for a test, I moved them. and replace a alert call.
}
```

to:

```
function callhello() {
    alert('<?php echo $_POST["word"]; ?>');
    //many other code, for a test, I moved them. and replace a alert call.
}
```

---

You need to change:

```
<body onload="JavaScript:callhello()">
```

to:

```
<body onload="javascript://callhello();">
```

Comment: With the first of these, that shouldn't make a difference, even if `language` is deprecated. With the second, the quotes are mismatched in the PHP source, but wouldn't be in the rendered HTML.

Comment: I have changed 2 parts as your said, but still nothing happens. but If I open `b.php` in the browser, it will pop up a empty box. can you check it for me? Thanks again.

Comment: @lonesomeday - I don't know PHP, was just trying to say that the alert would error with what the OP had.

Comment: @lonesomeday, yes, would u like to check it for me. here just 2 samll codes. thanks.